# How to read "allevents" using Python web3 (there's capability in web3.js)?

Tags: contract-development, events, python

Is there a mechanism to create a listener for all events being emitted from a smart contract for the python web3 library. There is a way to do it in web3.js:

```
myContract.events.allEvents([options][, callback])
```

However, I don't see a parallel in Python's library. There is a function to get all of the events in Hex but I am looking for the human readable version.

How to get events in Hex:

```
event_filter = web3.eth.filter({"address": contract_address})
```

web3.js documentation: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#events-allevents
web3.py documentation: http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html

Answer (score 2):

One option is to iterate all events and call `createFilter` on each of the events. Something like:

```
from web3.contract import ContractEvent

filters = [
  event.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')
  for event in myContract.events
  if issubclass(event, ContractEvent)
]
```

Comment: Here is another example if you need more https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico/blob/60872f904a95717ed5b77a64fbfb6b102b40306b/ico/tests/contracts/test_releasable.py#L39

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no direct way in web3.py to get all the events in a human-readable way.

You can use 3rd party sdk's like moralis to get the human-readable events of a particular event topic using event topic hash. This is an example.

```py
from moralis import evm_api

api_key = "Moralis_API_key"
params = {
    "address": "0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984", 
    "topic": "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef", 
}
body = {"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":True,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":True,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}


result = evm_api.events.get_contract_events(
    api_key=api_key,
    params=params,
    body=body,
)

print(result)
```

This is how the response will look like. Under the data key you can find the decoded log data in human readable form.

```
{
  "total": 3877564,
  "page": 0,
  "page_size": 100,
  "result": [
    {
      "transaction_hash": "0x9a8a251f9d07ae5ec6ec27d890857f58053dd22d4f8d77f5684e7675d6e63e32",
      "address": "0x1f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984",
      "block_timestamp": "2023-01-20T08:47:23.000Z",
      "block_number": "16446915",
      "block_hash": "0x10319286206a3a6c0c1a8191abdc9c22ce6e5931d87d61d3b6a8ccaddea4847a",
      "data": {
        "from": "0x4c6007e38ce164ed80ff8ff94192225fcdac68cd",
        "to": "0x9a9e5bdde9550e79bc397222799782227ba52422",
        "amount": "1106973445650000000000"
      }
    },
//...
//...
  }
```

You can find the API reference at: https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/reference/get-contract-events

I hope this helps.